# AWS Fargate Docker - How to print and see stdout/stderr from a headless ubuntu docker?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, logging, amazon-ec2

This may be a sort of 101 question, but in setting this up for the first time there are no hints about such a fundamental and common task. Basically I have a headless ubuntu running as a docker image inside AWS, which gets built via github actions CI/CD. All is running well.

Inside ubuntu I have some python scripts, let's say a custom server, cron jobs, some software running etc. How can I know, remotely, if there were any errors logged by any of these? Let's keep it simple: How can I print an error message, from a python server inside ubuntu, that I can read from outside docker? Does AWS have any kind of web interface for viewing stdout/stderr logs? Or at least an ssh console? Any examples somewhere?

Furthermore, I've set up my docker with healthchecks, to confirm that my servers running inside ubuntu are online and serving. Those work because I can test them in localhost by doing `docker ps` and shows Status 'healthy'. How do I see this same thing when live in AWS?

Have I really missed something this big? It feels like this should be the first thing flashing on the main page of setting up a docker on AWS.

Comment: Check out https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few things to unpack here, that you learn after digging through a lot of stuff you don't need in order to get started, just so you can know how to get started.

1. Docker will log by default the output of the startup processes that you've described your dockerfile setup, e.g. when you do `ENTRYPOINT bash -C /home/ubuntu/my_dockerfile_sh_scripts/myStartupScripts.sh`. If any subproceses spawned by those processes also log to stdout/stderr, the messages should bubble up to the host process, and therefore be shown in the docker log. If they don't bubble, look up subprocess stdout/stderr in linux.
2. Ok we know that, but where the heck is AWS's stats and logs page? Well in Amazon Cloudwatch™ of course. Didn't you already know about that term? Why, it says so right there when you create a docker, or on your ECS console next to your docker Clusters, or next to your running docker image Service. OH WAIT! No, no it does not! There is no utterance of "Cloudwatch" anywhere. Well there is this [one page](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home) that has "Cloudwatch" on it, which you can get to if you know the url, but hey look at that, you don't actually see any sort of logs coming from your code in docker anywhere on there so ..yeah. So where do you see your actual logs and output? There is this Logs tab, in your Service's page (the page of the currently running docker image): `https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?region=eu-central-1#/clusters/your-cluster-name/services/your-cluster-docker-image-service/logs`. This generically named and not-described tab, shows a log not of some status for the service, from the AWS side, but actually shows you the docker logs I mentioned in point 1. Ok. How do I view this as a raw file or access this remotely via script? Well I don't know. I guess you'll find out about that basic common task, after reading a couple of manuals about setting up the AWS CLI (another thing you didn't know existed).
3. Like I said in point 1, docker cannot log generic operating system log messages, or show you log files generated by your server, or just other software or jobs that are running that weren't described and started by your dockerfile/config. So how do we get AWS to see that? Well, It's a bit of a pain in the ass, you have to either replace your docker image's default OS's (e.g. ubuntu) logging driver with `sudo yum install -y awslogs` and [set that up](https://www.justdocloud.com/2019/03/24/send-docker-logs-aws-cloudwatch/), or you can create symbolic links between specific log files and the stdout/stderr stream ([docker docs mention of this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/)). Also check [Mark B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66550420/480859). But probably the easiest thing is to write your own little scripts with short messages that print out to the main process what's the status of things. Usually that's all you need unless you're an enterprise.
4. Is there any ssh or otherwise an AWS online command line interface page into the running docker, like you get in your localhost docker desktop? So you could maybe `cd` and `ls` browse or search for files and see if everything's fine? No. Make your own. Or better yet, avoid needing that in the first place, even though it's inconvenient for R&D.
5. Healthchecks. Where the heck do I see my docker healthchecks? The equivalent to the localhost method of just running the `docker ps` command. Well by default there aren't any healthchecks shown anywhere on AWS. Why would you need healthchecks anyway? So what if your dockerfile has `HEALTHCHECK`s defined?.. You have to set that up in Fargate™ (..whatever fargate even means cause the name's not written anywhere ("UX")). You have to create what is called a new Task Definition Revision. Go to your Clusters in Amazon ECS. Go to your cluster. Then you click on your Service's entry in the Task Definition column of the services table on the bottom. You click on Create New Revision (new task definition revision). On the new page you click on your container in the Container Definitions table. On the new page you scroll down to HEALTHCHECK, bingo! Now what is this? What commands to I paste in here? It's not automatically taking the HEALTHCHECK that I defined in my dockerfile, so does that mean I must write something else here?? What environment are the healthchecks even run in? Is it my docker? Is it linux? Here's the answer: you paste in this box, what you already wrote in your dockerfile's HEALTHCHECK. Just use `http://127.0.0.1` (localhost) as you would in your local docker desktop testing environment. Now click Update. Click Create. K, now we're still not done. Go back to your Amazon ECS / Clusters / cluster. Click on your service name in the services table. Click Update. Select the latest Revision. Check "force new deployment". Then keep clicking Next until finally you click Update Service. You can also define what triggers your image to be shut down on healthcheck fail. For example if it ran out of ram. Now #Amazon, I hope you take this answer and staple it to your shitty ass ECS experience.

---

I swear the relentlessly, exclusively bottom-up UX of platforms like AWS and Azure are what is keeping the tutorial blogger industry alive.. How would I know what AWS CloudWatch is, or that it even exists? There are no hints about these things anywhere while you set up. You'd think the first thing that flashes on your screen after you completed a docker setup would be **"hey, 99.9% of people right now need to set up logging. You should use cloudwatch. And here's how you connect healthchecks to cloudwatch"**. But no, of course not..!

Instead, AWS's "engineer" approach here seems to be: here's a grid of holes in the wall, and here's a mess of wires next to it in a bucket. Now in order to do the common frequently done tasks you want to do, you must first read the manual for each hole, and the manual for each wire in the bucket, then find all of the holes and wires you need, and plug them in the right order (and for the right order you need to find a blog post because that always involves some level of not following the docs and definitely also magic).
I guess it's called "job security" for if you're an enterprise server engineer :)

Comment: This is pretty fabulous, thank you! (if you had a blog I'd read it)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, I found the [AWS Wiki](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-eks-troubleshoot-container-logs/), the `/dev/stdout` symbolic link doesn't work to me, but `/proc/1/fd/1` symbolic link works to me.

Here is the solution:

Step 1. Add those commands to your Dockerfile.

```
# forward logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /var/log/console.log \
    && ln -sf /proc/1/fd/2 /var/log/error.log
```

Step 2. refer to "Mark B"'s step2.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** Update your docker image by deleting all the log files you care about, and replacing them with symbolic links to stdout or stderr, for example to capture logs in an nginx container I may do the following in the `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

**Step 2.** Configure [the awslogs driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html) in the ECS Task Definition, like so:

```
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "my-log-group",
          "awslogs-region": "my-aws-region",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "my-log-prefix"
        }
      }
```

And as long as you gave the ECS Execution Role permission to write to AWS Logs, log data will start appearing in CloudWatch Logs.